# Opacity in HERE Map Image API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am trying to change the opacity of the polygon fill when using the Region  Resource from the HERE Map Image API.

Has anyone been able to get this right?

The resource [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/resource-region.html) does not mention opacity anywhere. The only options available to alter the fill is `fc,fc0,fc1,...` which specifies the fill color itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And fc color parameter can be set with transparency. The first 2 digits in the hex value represents transparency and rest of 6 digits is rgb color:

```
fc1=80FF0000
```

Please refer to this article for more detail: 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/examples-region-usa.html